# How to compare two rations of float numbers with DBL_EPSILON?

Tags: c, comparison

I want to write the following program: I would like to scanf length of three sides of a triangle (in float). Then I would like to scanf again three sides of a second triangle. The next thing is to find out, whether these two triangles are similar. It means that if a ratio of one side in first triangle and the same side in the second triangle equals to ratio of a second side in first triangle and the same size in the second triangle and the same for third side, than the triangles are similar.

```
if(mid1/mid2 == min1/min2 && mid1/mid2 == max1/max2){
printf("Triangles are similar.\n");
```

The thing is, if I have two triangles with the dimensions: First triangle (9.861 9.865 9.883) and Second triangle (9861 9883 9865), the program says that the triangles are not similar. How to use and write a DBL_EPSILON so that it would create an acceptable deviation and program would work for those numbers?

Comment: If you have two pairs of non-zero floating-point numbers, (A, B) and (a, b), and the real-number ratio of A to B equals the real-number ratio of a to b, then the quotients `A/B` and `a/b` calculated with floating-point arithmetic will be equal. Thus, if the triangles are similar, the ratios of their sides will be equal. The converse is not true; if the quotients computed in floating-point are equal, it does not prove the numbers have the same real-number ratios, due to rounding in floating-point arithmetic. It is likely possible to devise tests other than simply comparing quotients…

Comment: … that would determine whether the numbers have the same real-number ratios. However, it appears a problem you have is that the numbers you have, say (A, B, C) and (a, b, c) are not actually the sides of the triangles because they have been converted to a floating-point format, and rounding errors were introduces during this conversion. For example, if 9.861 is converted to binary floating point, the result is a number near but not equal to 9.861. At this point, the information about whether the triangles truly are similar has been lost, and it cannot be recovered from the floating-point…

Comment: … numbers. You could devise some tests that also return true indications that the original numbers are the sides of similar triangles, but any such tests would necessarily also sometimes return false indications that the original numbers are the sides of similar triangles when they are not. Devising various tests depends on how much error one is willing to accept.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe something like this:

```
#define DBL_EPSILON 0.0001

int test(float a, float b) {
    float c = a - b;
    return DBL_EPSILON <= c && c <= DBL_EPSILON;
}

void your_func() {
    ...
    if (test(mid1/mid2, min1/min2) && test(mid1/mid2, max1/max2))
        printf("Triangles are similar.\n");    
    ...
}
```